# usding sed to replace multi-words

Tags: linux, bash, sed, replace, tr

Is there an example of if you want to replace multi-words with one word

for example input: dog apple orange banana pear
output dog cat cat banana cat

I have solved with this below is there is a better way(better than sed)? by not typing cat three times:

```
sed -e 's/apple/cat/g;s/orange/cat/g;s/pear/cat/g'
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace the strings at once using `OR` operator

```
sed -e 's/apple\|orange\|pear/cat/g' filename
```

Comment: Thanks, that will work for me.